# Read symbols and text from PDF using Itext

Tags: c#, itext

I have been using the following C# code to read text from PDF file:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;               
            // file properties
            Dictionary<string, string> infodict = reader.Info;
            string strText = string.Empty;
            PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            for (int page = 1; page <= n; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();    
                String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);                   
                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s;
                reader.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(strText);
```

This code can't read symbols in the pdf file. Is there any way i can also read symbols from PDF file?

Comment: What is this line doing?:
   s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)))

I would remove this line entirely.

Comment: s reads the text of entire page.

Comment: s, is converting to UTF8, then encoding to ASCII, then back to UTF8, how is it "reading" the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use the LocationTextExtractionStrategy instead of the SimpleTextExtractionStrategy

Comment: Both strategies use the same character information, `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` merely tries to sort while `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` assumes the information already to be in the correct order. Thus, replacing does not help when the *code can't read symbols in the pdf file*.